# In Julia, declare AbstractVector{AbstractVector}

Tags: julia, abstract-data-type

I'm interested in defining a struct that has a field which is a vector of vectors. Potentially (but not necessarily), the inner vectors would be of type `SVector` (defined in the StaticArrays package). My naive approach would be to declare the field `x::AbstractVector{AbstractVector{T}}`; however, julia doesn't regard, say, `Vector{SVector{3, Float64}}` to be an instance of `AbstractVector{AbstractVector}`. For that matter, it doesn't regard `Vector{Vector{64}}` to be `AbstractVector{AbstractVector}` either. It seems as though the contained type has to be a concrete type, or left out entirely. Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Use `AbstractVector{<:AbstractVector}`

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Ah, naturally! Thanks! If you make it an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AbstractVector{<:AbstractVector}` as this is a construct accepting any vector whose element type is a subtype of `AbstractVector`.

Instead `AbstractVector{AbstractVector}` requires element type to be `AbstractVector` exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Using structs with abstract fields are not generally recommended, especially for performance reasons. In a struct field `AbstractVector{<:AbstractVector}` is abstract, even if the eltype is concrete.

Using `AbstractVector{<:AbstractVector}` in a function signature is fine, but probably not in a struct definition. Try this instead:

```
struct Foo{T<:AbstractVector{<:AbstractVector}}
    x::T
end
```

This will give you a concretely typed field, where the type of the field `x` is encoded in the type parameter.